# What is the difference when including <script> tag in HTML's header or body

Tags: javascript, html

What is the difference in behavior / performance when including  tag in body or head part of html document.
Also i noticed that google analytics is usually embedded at the end of body. why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats Pros and Cons: putting javascript in head and putting just before the body close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451417/whats-pros-and-cons-putting-javascript-in-head-and-putting-just-before-the-body)

Comment: As a sidenote: Google now recommends putting tracking code in the `<head>` section: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the time you want to include scripts at the bottom of the body section.  The basic reason is to ensure that the page (and consequently the DOM) has fully loaded before any javascript is executed upon it.

Additionally, since downloading scripts blocks the browser from downloading anything else at the same time, the page will appear to load faster if the page elements are loaded before the script.  However, unless you are a huge website that gets lots of traffic like Yahoo or Google, you probably do not need to consider this.

Comment: +1 However, the second point is important regardless of how huge the site is. A 2 second delay because of SCRIPT elements in the HEAD is a bad thing for **every** web-site.

Answer (score 9):

From Yahoo! Developers Network: [Put Scripts at the Bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)