# can't open jquery popup window

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, popupwindow

I think my question is great basic but I am newbie to jquery and I don't understand why it doesn't work. I would like to do something like google calendar. When you click on a day, a popup window showing a form is displayed. 
I began with a simple example of popup . I did exactly like in the tuto http://jqframework.com/jqpopup/

```
<input type="button" id="open_btn" value="open the 1st jQpopup"/>

<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#open_btn").click(function () {

      $("#sampleformdiv").jqpopup_open(this.id);

   });

});
```

Here are the js scripts that I included:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/ci_calendar/application/views/assets/js/jqDnR.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/ci_calendar/application/views/assets/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/ci_calendar/application/views/assets/js/jquery.jqpopup.min.js'></script>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the button. 
Could anyone help me please?
Thanks !

Comment: Are you running this on a public webserver or on a local development machine? Also, your document.ready call should be in the head of your document.

Comment: j08691, it's not required. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451417/whats-pros-and-cons-putting-javascript-in-head-and-putting-just-before-the-body

Comment: may be u forgot include jquery ?

Comment: are there any javascript errors in your console..

Comment: What you want to achieve? `$("#sampleformdiv").jqpopup_open(this.id);`