# Phonegap - why jquery loaded in body and not head?

Tags: cordova

I noticed many phonegap templates put the javascript (such as jquery or jquery mobile) at the end of the body tag.

In normal html pages, the jquery etc. files are loaded in the head part of the document.

Is there an advantage to putting it in the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link offers an excellent discussion on the topic: [Whats Pros and Cons: putting javascript in head and putting just before the body close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451417/whats-pros-and-cons-putting-javascript-in-head-and-putting-just-before-the-body).

But in general, putting the JavaScript at the end of the body gives a better and faster feel to the user. In addition, any JavaScript placed in the head will run before getting to the body, meaning your JavaScript might not know what elements are present. This would greatly affect a function that runs as soon as your JavaScript file loads. Basically, the best practice I know of is to put your JavaScript at the end of the body, unless you have a good reason not to.