# javascript upload an image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, loader

I try to upload and draw an image into a canvas. 
I have the html code for button and canvas and js code for onchange event.
My code does not work and I do not have any errors to figure out what is going on.

Comment: What are you expecting as a result, i tried it and the image is being loaded inside the canvas. Can you specify more details 'on what is not working' ?

Comment: I have the same code but in separated files for js and html (same folder). I link them with <script type=“text/javascript” src=“myFileName.js”></script>, and nothig happens with my image loader

Comment: Are you adding the script tag in the `<head>` ?

Comment: you must add it at the end of the body, otherwise it won't work. can you open the browser console and check if there is any error in the logs ?

Comment: Add this `<script src="myFileName.js"></script>` before the body closing tag </body>

Comment: Yes, the script tag is in the head tag and I tried to put the code in the html file and it work ( script tag type="text/javascript")

Comment: So it's fine now ? If any suspicion, check it here https://embed.plnkr.co/HjeuLH9WzL0IFj1ZEIBw/.

Comment: Finally it works!! Thanks a lot! The solution is to " 
Add this <script src="myFileName.js"></script> before the body closing tag </body>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is by simply including your **scripts** at the end of the **body** before the closing tag `</body>`.

Your html code will appear like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="buttonsDiv" >
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" title="Upload Image" class="normal-button" id="uploadBtn"/>            
    </div>
    <canvas id= "myImgCanvas" title="Drop an image here to upload" ></canvas>

    <script src="myFileName.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you must pay attention when you should/ should not include your scripts in the `<head>` tag vs including it at the end of the `</body>` tag. You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451441/1387113) for the best practice.