# Append for loop to div in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to learn javascript and I think I have a working json script with a loop to grab the data but I'm having trouble figuring out how to append the data to my div.  After I figure this out I'm going to redo it in jquery (because I'm trying to learn that as well).

Let's say my div id is #wrapper

```
for (var i = 0; i < providerlisting.length; i++) {
document.write('<div class="entry panel row"> \
    <div class="large-4 columns first"> \
            <div class="name">' + providerlisting[i].nametitle + '</div> \
            <div class="specialty">' + providerlisting[i].caretype + '</div> \
            <div class="peferred">' + providerlisting[i].preferredprovider + '</div> \
        </div> \
        <div class="large-3 columns second"> \
            <div class="address">' + providerlisting[i].address1 + '<br /> \
            ' + providerlisting[i].address2 + '<br /> \
            ' + providerlisting[i].citystatezip + ' \
            </div> \
        </div> \
        <div class="large-3 columns third"> \
            <img src="' + providerlisting[i].coverage + '" alt="example"> \
        </div> \
        <div class="large-2 columns fourth"> \
            <div class="status">' + providerlisting.status + '</div> \
            <a data-dropdown="actionsMenu2" class="actions button small secondary round dropdown" href="#">Actions</a><br> \
            <ul id="actionsMenu2" data-dropdown-content="" class="f-dropdown"> \
                <li><a href="' + providerlisting[i].psn + '">Generate PSN</a></li> \
                <li><a href="' + providerlisting[i].dcontact + '">Download Contact</a></li> \
                <li><a href="' + providerlisting[i].save + '">Save to Provider List</a></li> \
                <li><a href="' + providerlisting[i].rating + '">View Healthgrades Rating</a></li> \
            </ul> \
        </div> \
    </div>  \
')};
```

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5677816/467133

Good luck with learning jQuery!

Comment: My advice would be to delete everything and start over, as that is a mess! Avoid using document.write and long strings of HTML.

Comment: Adeneo, I'm trying to learn javascript.  Please try to be constructive in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `document.write`, that's a direct output (where ever the `<script>` may lie). And, without getting in to DOM objects, you're going to need to append to `.innerHTML`. e.g.

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (...){
  /*document.write(*/
  wrapper.innerHTML +=
    '<div ...'
  ;
  /*);*/
}
```

Now, you *could* start using DOM elements instead. for example:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (...){
  // create the outer div (with classes 'entry panel row'):
  var entry_panel_row = document.createElement('div');

  // add the class names:
  entry_panel_row.className = 'entry panel row';

  // instead of document.write, add the HTML to this new element...
  entry_panel_row.innerHTML += '<div class="large-4 ...</div>';

  // now append the element (as a whole) to wrapper
  wrapper.appendChild(entry_panel_row);
}
```

Going further, instead of using strings, you can create the elements one by one appending them to each parent. Then, once you've compiled the entire DOM element in to `entry_panel_row` you can proceed to `wrapper.appendChild(entry_panel_row)`.

---

jQuery is (a little) easier than `el = document.createElement` and `parent.appendChild(el)` over and over, and the nomenclature takes a bit getting used to, but here's what you had. I figure I would translate it so you can see jQuery (you had mentioned learning it):

```
for (var i = 0; i < providerlisting.length; i++){
  var pl = providerlisting[i]; // shorthand reference

  // begin building you DOM element
  $('<div>')
    .addClass('entry panel row') // css classes
    .append( // children
      $('<div>').addClass('large-4 columns first').append(
        $('<div>').addClass('name').text(pl.nametitle),
        $('<div>').addClass('specialty').text(pl.caretype),
        $('<div>').addClass('preferred').text(pl.preferredprovider)
      ),
      $('<div>').addClass('large-3 columns second').append(
        $('<div>').addClass('address').html(pl.address1 + '<br />' + pl.address2 + '<br />' + pl.citystatezip)
      ),
      $('<div>').addClass('large-3 columns third').append(
        $('<img>').attr({'src':pl.coverage,'alt':'example'})
      ),
      $('<div>').addClass('large-2 columns fourth').append(
        $('<div>').addClass('status').text(pl.status),
        $('<a>').addClass('actions button small secondary round dropdown').prop('href','#').data('dropdown','actionsMenu2').text('Actions'),
        '<br />',
        $('<ul>').prop('id','actionsMenu2').addClass('f-dropdown').data('dropdownContent','').append(
          $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').prop('href',pl.psn).text('Generate PSN')
          ),
          $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').prop('href',pl.dcontact).text('Download Contact')
          ),
          $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').prop('href',pl.save).text('Save to Provider List')
          ),
          $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').prop('href',pl.rating).text('View Healthgrades Rating')
          ),
        )
      )
    )
    .appendTo('#wrapper'); // add it to #wrapper
}
```

Comment: @Chad: Updated it with jQuery version (for your viewing pleasure). Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I used the DOM set up you provided above and while the code checks out in my IDE, it's not appending anything to the wrapper div.  I included the script externally in the head tag and not inline. I can see that the correct script is loaded but nothing shows.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Chad: In the `<head>`? Chances are JavaScript isn't aware of an element called `#wrapper` yet [as you read in to jQuery, that's the primary reason why everything is housed in a document ready event]. Unless it's Modernizr, all `<script>`s should belong just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: I just saved it as json.js and then did a   <script src="/scripts/json.js"></script> call in the Head.  I did this for my modals and it seemed to work fine.  I'm just wondering why I would place it at the bottom.

Comment: JavaScript should always be a supplement to your design not a crutch. By placing it at the bottom you get faster page renderings with the added benefit of JavaScript support.

Comment: @Chad: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383045/is-put-scripts-at-the-bottom-correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHtml = document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHtml + 'new content';
```