# MP3-Player in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Would somebody be so kind to tell me what I did wrong? I want to create a mp3-player with css, html and javascript. The only thing the script does at the moment is to start or to stop the audio-file. The problem is, that I always get an error.: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null;
But I don't know why.
Thank you very much for your help!!!

Script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Video | Audio</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var hear = document.getElementById('#listen');
    document.getElementById('#control').addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(hear.paused) {
            hear.play();
        } else {
            hear.pause();
        }
    })


    </script>

    <audio id="listen" src="song.mp3">
        ERROR
    </audio>

    <button id="control">control</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The id comes after your inline script

Comment: This has very probably been answered before on SO. Simplest way to solve this is to add [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) to your `script` tag or move the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: What do you mean with the id comes after my inline script

Comment: Remove the '#' from your `getElementById` calls. Example: `document.getElementById('listen')`.

Comment: But the problem without the '#' is the same

Comment: did you also remove the one from `document.getElementById('#control')` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [load and execute order of scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)

Comment: I'll try my hand at clarifying some previous comments :) In your example, the code is read and executed in the same order it's written. Therefore, your `<script>` block is executed before your `<audio>` element is added to the page. When your script searches for the `listen` element, it isn't on the page yet, because it comes *after* the `<script>`.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383045/is-put-scripts-at-the-bottom-correct), best practice is to put your scripts at the end of the body tag to avoid timing problems like this. Here's how you should change your code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Video | Audio</title>
</head>
<body>



    <audio id="listen" src="song.mp3">
        ERROR
    </audio>

    <button id="control">control</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var hear = document.getElementById('listen');
    document.getElementById('control').addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(hear.paused) {
            hear.play();
        } else {
            hear.pause();
        }
    })


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The reason it wasn't working before is that web pages get parsed from top to bottom, including scripts, so your button didn't exist by the time your script executed, which is why your script couldn't find it. Additionally, when you use getElementById, you need to call it without using the hash.

Comment: You're welcome! Not sure why my answer got 3 down votes, it seems to be the only one that works.

Comment: @user4825080 Don't forget to click the checkmark next to one of the answers to mark it as the accepted answer!

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh sry I forgot, but at the moment it tolds me, that I have to wait 3 minutes until I can do that

Comment: it probably got down voted (not by me) because this is just a variant of a question that has been asked 1000 different ways and neither explains why it works or why it is considered "best practice" nor any of the many different alternatives that would work, preferably by linking to existing questions/answers.

Comment: @technosaurus Thank you for the explanation, still learning the ropes here.